# Shadow under status bar on android apps

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Hi all i'm using phonegap to create an android app and no matter what i do there seems to be a shadow under the status bar, a mockup attached. Any ideas on how to remove it please? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think yor are taking about fading edgs

try it for your layout

```
  android:fadingEdge="none"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! One more question where do i add this?

Comment: add this to your layout in xml.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried it and it doesn't work, heres what i have. 

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, FootballSocial"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    />
</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

try this for your linear layout in javacode

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(your linear layout id)
ll.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```